# SQL CASE and CAST together causes aggregation error when grouping other fields

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a query that has to convert values into decimals and divide them. I need to only divide when a value is greater than 0, otherwise it throws an error. My query is below. For some reason adding the CASE statement causes an aggregation error. I've seen examples that say to wrap in a SUM, but that won't work for my case. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT
    EmailName,
    SUM(Sent) as Sent,
    SUM(Delivered) as Delivered,
    SUM(UniqueOpens) as UniqueOpens,
    SUM(TotalOpens) as TotalOpens,
    SUM(UniqueClicks) as UniqueClicks,
    SUM(TotalClicks) as TotalClicks,
    SUM(Unsubscribes) as Unsubscribes,
    CAST(SUM(UniqueOpens) AS FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(Delivered) AS FLOAT) as OpenRate
FROM 
    [Non Triggered Sends Last Month]
GROUP BY 
    EmailName
```

This works if UniqueOpens is greater than 0, but fails otherwise

This throws an aggregation warning

```
SELECT
    EmailName,
    SUM(Sent) as Sent,
    SUM(Delivered) as Delivered,
    SUM(UniqueOpens) as UniqueOpens,
    SUM(TotalOpens) as TotalOpens,
    SUM(UniqueClicks) as UniqueClicks,
    SUM(TotalClicks) as TotalClicks,
    SUM(Unsubscribes) as Unsubscribes,
    CASE WHEN UniqueOpens > 0 THEN CAST(SUM(UniqueOpens) AS FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(Delivered) AS FLOAT) ELSE CAST(SUM(UniqueOpens) AS FLOAT) END as OpenRate
FROM 
    [Non Triggered Sends Last Month]
GROUP BY 
    EmailName
```

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Column 'C7211451.Non Triggered Sends Last Month.UniqueOpens' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case statement needs to have a SUM in it too.

```
CASE WHEN UniqueOpens > 0
```

needs to be

```
CASE WHEN SUM(UniqueOpens) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to `SUM(UniqueOpens)`

```
SELECT
EmailName,
SUM(Sent) as Sent,
SUM(Delivered) as Delivered,
SUM(UniqueOpens) as UniqueOpens,
SUM(TotalOpens) as TotalOpens,
SUM(UniqueClicks) as UniqueClicks,
SUM(TotalClicks) as TotalClicks,
SUM(Unsubscribes) as Unsubscribes,
CASE WHEN SUM(UniqueOpens) > 0 THEN CAST(SUM(UniqueOpens) AS FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(Delivered) AS FLOAT) ELSE CAST(SUM(UniqueOpens) AS FLOAT) END as OpenRate
FROM [Non Triggered Sends Last Month]
GROUP BY EmailName
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a value when the unique delivered is non-positive?  I would just go for `NULL`:

```
 SUM(UniqueOpens) * 1.0 / NULLIF(SUM(Delivered), 0) as OpenRate
```

However, if you want to prevent division by zero, I would suggest comparing the *denominator*, not the numerator:

```
 (CASE WHEN SUM(Delivered) > 0
       THEN SUM(UniqueOpens) * 1.0 / SUM(Delivered)
       ELSE 0  -- I'm assuming these SUM(Delivered) is a non-negative integer
  END) as OpenRate
```

I usually use the shorthand of `* 1.0` to prevent integer division.  Conversion to float is equally good.

Answer (score 0):

Use sum Aggregation on Case statement

```
SELECT
EmailName,
SUM(Sent) as Sent,
SUM(Delivered) as Delivered,
SUM(UniqueOpens) as UniqueOpens,
SUM(TotalOpens) as TotalOpens,
SUM(UniqueClicks) as UniqueClicks,
SUM(TotalClicks) as TotalClicks,
SUM(Unsubscribes) as Unsubscribes,
SUM(CASE WHEN UniqueOpens > 0 THEN 
CAST(UniqueOpens AS FLOAT)/CAST(Delivered AS FLOAT)
 ELSE CAST(UniqueOpens AS FLOAT) )END as OpenRate
FROM [Non Triggered Sends Last Month]
GROUP BY EmailName
```